# Can this algorithm be written as an equation?

Tags: algorithms

Found an algorithm to compute the square root of a positive number A, using the following iteration:
$$s_n=\frac{1}{2}(s_{n-1}+\frac{A}{s_{n-1}}),\ n=0,1, ...$$
and $s_{n-1}$ is an initial estimate of $\sqrt{A}$.
This iteration converges as $s_n\approx s_{n-1} \implies s_n\approx\sqrt{A}$
In a spreadsheet implementation this converges quite fast.
Is this something that can be written as an equation?
If so, I would like to learn how to do this.

Comment: But if $s_n\approx \sqrt{A}$, then all to the left of $\sqrt{A}$ in your equation $= 1$  And defeats the purpose of obtaining $\sqrt{A}$ from *A* and *n*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes from applying [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to the equation
$$
s^2-A=0.
$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing to Newton's method, so this will always need some iterations to reach an approximation?  I've seen some recursive difference equations converted to an equation as a function of n.

Comment: Yes. The method is rapidly convergent (the technical term is quadratic convergence) and usually few iterations are needed.